# ios AVPlayer Button action not getting trigged

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm trying to add button on top of a video player. Button is getting added but the click event is not getting triggered from iOS simulator.

However, the event gets triggered accurately when I do it programmatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    guard let url = URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8") else {
        return
    }
    // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds



    let btn = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    btn.setTitle("Do stuff 1", for: .normal)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 330, width: 300, height: 300)
    btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    btn.addTarget( self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    //btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    //controller.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(btn)
    playerLayer.addSublayer(btn.layer)

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

Please help. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to press the button using storyboard button because it is behind the layer.

You have two options.

1) In storyboard Create a separate view where you can add your video layer instead of adding directly to main view  and button top of it

2) Change Z position of button

`button.layer.zPosition = 1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding the button's layer rather than adding the button as a subview.  Here's the full code you can cut and paste.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        guard let url = URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8") else {
            return
        }
        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        let btn = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        btn.setTitle("Do stuff 1", for: .normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 330, width: 300, height: 300)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.addTarget( self, action: #selector(self.pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(btn)
        player.play()
    }

    @objc func pressButton(button: Any) {
        print("PRESSED")
    }
}
```

The main thing though was simply the **view.addSubview(btn)**.